# Why is region monitoring working on simulator but not on my actual device?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I am trying to enable geofencing for region monitoring, and it seems to be working on the simulator, but when I upload it to my device I get an error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)`. Any ideas why it works in the simulator, but not on my actual device? I am following this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial)

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("Monitoring failed for region with identifier: \(region) \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Two usual suspects would be the permission and number od regions. Did you ask the user for permission to ise location? How many regions did you try to monitor? There is a limit of about 20 regions.

Comment: I only have 3 regions, and yes I do ask for permission. Like I said it works on the simulator.

Comment: What sort of device do you have? iPhone? iPad? iPod?

Comment: iPhone 6s running 10.2, not sure if this affects anything but it is jailbroken

Comment: Yeah, turns out it's because I am jailbroken. Any idea why that may be?